# How do I add columns with same name in a same dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind, cbind

I want to add numbers of the same `Start` while retaining the form of the dataframe. Below is how my dataframe looks currently.

```
'data.frame':   305897 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date  : int  20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 ...
 $ Start : chr  "ST-10" "ST-10" "ST-10" "ST-10" ...
 $ Number: int  1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
```

And below is what I want to make.

```
'data.frame':   14232 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date  : int  20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 20220701 ...
 $ Start : chr  "ST-10" "ST-1000" "ST-1002" "ST-351" ...
 $ Number: int  50 82 4 32 ...
```

I first tried using `rbind` `cbind` `merge` but those are not working; maybe since they're only for merging different dataframes? What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You're not adding columns, you're adding rows.  The difference is important.

Comment: @Limey I don't think so... If I understood appropriately, isn't the link about combining 2 dataframes? I want to combine rows of one dataframe

Comment: Combining one data.frame makes no sense: it's already combined.  Please follow the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*.  You'll need to post your input data frame(s) [preferably by using `dput()`] and your desired output based on that input.